# read_html does not work on rstudio server

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-compute-engine, rvest, rstudio-server

I have been scraping weather information from accuweather for a while now using rvest. The code works perfectly every time on Rstudio, but recently I moved to Rstudio server and R cannot execute the read_html line. My Rstudio server lives on a google compute engine instance - I wonder if that has anything to do with it?

This is the code in question:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url<-"https://www.accuweather.com/en/au/melbourne/26216/may-weather/26216?year=2020"
webpage <- read_html(url)
```

I cannot proceed from this to the rest of the code; R will attempt to run the 'read_html' line but stall there. I have to manually press the stop button after a while because it doesn't seem to work. On my computer the line runs almost instantly. Here's a SS.

[image]

My packages are all updated。 What seems to be the problem?

Comment: does it timeout? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No I am not behind a proxy, and I'm not sure if it'll timeout because I don't give it a chance to. Maximum I've waited was for about 10mins or so and then I just stopped the process. I think it's just rvest because when I scrape with httr in my other scripts (GET and POST) they work perfectly fine.